# PHP SoapRequest: get response

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to implement a soaprequest and making the call does seem to work. The only problem is: I don't know how to receive the response data. My code looks like this:

```
$auth = array(
    'UsernameToken' => array(
        'Username' => 'xxx',
        'Password' => 'yyyy'
    )
);
$header = new SoapHeader('xs','Security',$auth, 0);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
$client->__setLocation('http://example.com/test.php');
$params = array(
    ... 
    'trace' => 1,
    'cache_wsdl' => 0
);
try {
    $response = $client->getSomeData($params);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Exception: ".$e->getMessage();
}
print_r($response);
```

This results in an empty page, because $response is empty. But the test.php file is called (I tried with a simple mail() command and it sends the mail every time I call the page with the soapclient).

So I guess the soap response is somehow sent to the test.php file - right? How do I get it? If I do not set the location, I get a nullpointerexception, so I have to do that. I tried

```
$client->__getLastResponse()
```

that's empty too.

What can I do, how do I get the soap response data? Any hints would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you set the `trace` option when instantiating the SoapClient?

Comment: I tried that, doesn't make any difference